# In mathematical optimization, are sequential quadratic programming and sequential least squares programming the same thing?

Tags: optimization

The Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) that I am talking about is based on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming). And the Sequential Least SQuares Programming (SLSQP) is based on [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#id17)

Comment: I don't have access to algorithm documentation, so I really don't know what Sequential Least SQuares Programming is.  The link https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/tree/master/slsqp may give a bit of a guess.  That said, Sequential Quadratic Programming describes a family of algorithms of which there are many variants, differing in such things as use of trust regions vs. line search, use of actual Hessian (Newton) vs. Quasi-Newton (Newton), and many other important details.

Comment: The Scipy docs say that they use an implementation described in "A software package for sequential quadratic programming", so I would assume they mean the same thing. Least squares is a quadratic problem.

Comment: They are the same. Check out this link http://degenerateconic.com/slsqp/

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually SQP and SLSQP sovles the same subproblem of Quadratic Programming (QP) ([see subproblem here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming)) on each algorithm step.

- In SQP the problem of QP is solved by methods of Quadratic Programming.
- In SLSQP to solve the problem of QP you should $LDL^{-1}$-factorize Lagrange Hessian and then solve a linear least squares problem.

[image: Least Squares Subproblem]

Check the article:

> Kraft, D. A software package for sequential quadratic
> programming. 1988. Tech. Rep. DFVLR-FB 88-28, DLR German Aerospace
> Center -- Institute for Flight Mechanics, Koln, Germany.